# Writing Strict XHTML 1.0

Tags: xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have an exam, where I will be provided a series of code snippets and asked to determine whether they are Valid or Invalid Strict XHTML1.0. I can't find any rules, or digestible resources online. Can anyone advise if there is a set of checks that I can memorise?

Comment: you checked https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/ ? Or does that fall under the category 'indigestible'? It contains all info you need, I think.

Comment: If you have to do by hand from a piece of paper, that's a lot of work. Those language specs are large! So... where to begin. You do know the XML syntax? That's rule #1, obviously, well-formed XML. Then there's the valid elements; how about this https://www.w3.org/2010/04/xhtml10-strict.html

Comment: You know what, I've been thinking. Maybe the topic itself is irrelevant, maybe they're just trying to find out how good your Google-fu is, by asking about a subject they never covered.

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate thing you can and should do is ensure the file is served as `application/xhtml+xml`. If you are creating a file and don't have access to server-side scripting then you simply need to create a file with a `.xhtml` extension and `application/xhtml+xml` via the developer tools in whichever browser you're using.

I *highly* recommend using Firefox; when you encounter an XML parsing error the whole page will be hidden, it will have a yellow background and display the error, it's line and column numbers in red text. It's extremely useful for quickly addressing malformed XML parsing errors.

Keep in mind that XHTML 1 (HTML4 equivalent) is outdated and I highly recommend using XHTML5. While I've updated my platform from XHTML 1 Strict to XHTML 5 (link in my profile) you will be exceptionally hard pressed to find better examples of stricter code that will adhere to XHTML5.

Also keep in mind that HTML (`text/html`) is handled by a browser's HTML parser whereas XHTML (`application/xhtml+xml`) is handled by a browser's XML parser.

An XML parser will catch malformed XML though it will *not* prevent duplicate `id` attributes from wreaking havoc in JavaScript (the first `id attribute of two or more identical values will always be targeted).

It should also be noted that XHTML1 defined attributes to have the same value as the attribute name:

**XHTML 1**

```
<select>
<option selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

**XHTML 5**

```
<select>
<option selected="true"></option>
</select>
```

XHTML5 defines *most* though not all (e.g. the `autocomplete` attribute) as having *boolean* values (e.g. `true` or `false`).

Lastly you can have everything completely XHTML1/5 compliant though if the media type/mime is `text/html` then your page is *not* XHTML in any form. One of the greatest advantages of XHTML is that is *has* to be served strictly; strict code can be dependably served loosely though loose code can not be dependently served strictly and I am not talking about doctypes.

Comment: Where does it say that the value of `selected` was changed from `selected` to `true` between XHTML 1 and 5?

Comment: @MrLister Everywhere attributes are defined as `boolean` in the actual spec. https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-option-element.html#attr-option-selected --- "The `selected` attribute is a boolean attribute."

Comment: No no, the term _boolean attribute_ doesn't mean the value should be `"true"` or `"false"`. It means that the attribute itself should be absent or present! If you run a XHTML5 file through the W3C validator, it complains about `selected="true"` but `selected="selected"` is OK. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fmrlister.1apps.com%2Ftest%2Ftest2.xhtml

Comment: In fact, if you write `selected="false"`, the browser will interpret this as selected, because the attribute is present. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute Note that there _are_ attributes in the (X)HTML5 spec that can have values `"true"` and `"false"`, such as `draggable`, but those are not called boolean attributes.

Comment: @MrLister Technically it's an old bug as I remember testing older versions of browsers (specifically Firefox) and as usual the XML parser is treated as a second class citizen.

Comment: @John - this is mostly a good answer, but @MrLister is correct and `selected="true"` spoils it somewhat. I encourage you to change it to `selected=""` which is valid XHTML5.

Comment: @John - No it isn't. See the [Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes)  in the spec. "NOTE: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether." Can't get much clearer than that.